# Jboss cache with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, caching, jboss

I am very new to this caching techniques. I just managed to configure JBossCache with Hibernate on JBoss AS 4.23 GA.

My question is Suppose I have two different configurations defined in the configuration file. One is optimistic-entity and second one is pessimistic-entity. I want to use optimistic-entity configuration for one set of entities and pessimistic-entity configuration for another set of entities. But hibernate provides only one set of configuration with hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cfg.entity="....  " which is common to all entities.

Now how can I use two different configurations for two sets of entities, one optmistic-entity and another one is pessimistic-entity.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: can you post fragments of the config you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

For JBoss 4.2.3.GA, follow this instructions and forget about the rest:
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/NewJBossCache14xBasedHibernate32CacheProvider

hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cfg.entity option is for a different Hibernate version to the one shipped in JBoss 4.2.3.GA.

By the way, I'd stick to pessimistic for JBoss Cache 1.x. It's more robust and road tested.